# How to use bl_label inside an operator?

Tags: python, add-on

How do I reference the bl_label inside operators? I want to know the name of the operator based on the bl_label to be precise.

Comment: Hi. I hope you don't mind my edit. If you meant something else please edit the question and correct it.

Comment: @MartinZ it is a slippery slope to answer, and then edit question based on answer. Recommend asking, via comments,  for clarification first.

Comment: It wasn't formed clearly. I believe this was the intended question and encouraged yarun can to correct me if I am wrong. You might be right though. I will try to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `bl_label` inside the operator's code as a variable so after that you can reference it as any other variable inside the operator. It would be `self.bl_label`:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.bl_label)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```